# binding to large datasets to JQuery controls

Tags: javascript, html, http, stream, wcf-rest

I have a JQuery widget that has a map [uses bing maps] and a grid control. The data that needs to be shown is pretty huge [1 million - 100K records].

The data that grid and map shows are common. Now even though, I wish to get the data in a paginated way for the grid, the map needs to locate all the points [1 million]. Since the map needs only latitude and longitudes, I was planning to get the data separately for map and grid. -i.e. in one call get the all 1 million latitudes and longitudes and in another call get just first 100 records for the grid.

I was also thinking if http streaming would be of any help in this regard. I am using RESTful apis to get data from database. Is it possible that I directly send the streamed response from the server to the javascript side. While sending the data to client, I send packets of data and then client keep on polling for the data as and when it comes. My question is does this make the process complex and if not do I need to use a web socket to achieve this?

Please let me know which approach is better and also let me know if streaming of data would be a good idea or not.

Thanks,
Anirban

Comment: This question is a little too vague and there is no reasonable way to answer it. It needs some work. I would say this: there is no way you are going to render all 1 million records of data, so don't load or worry about them. Properly target the data you need, and load that. Then load more on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a million coordinates to JavaScript will only lead to a lot of pain. Your best option for viewing large datasets on a JavaScript map is to turn it into an image on the server side and overlay it on the map. Take a look at this code project: http://ajaxmapdataconnector.codeplex.com/